Gradio for live voice conversation
I'm struggling to set up gradio for my live voice assitant, the user and the system are supposed to talk to each other continuosly kinda like siri but i don't know what to use for inputs and outputs variables
`conversation_interface = gr.Interface(
fn=voice_assistant,
inputs=gr.inputs.Microphone(label="Speak Here"),
outputs=gr.outputs.Textbox(label="Assistant's Response"),
title="Bright Dentistry",
description="Welcome to Bright Dentistry where we take care of your teeth!.",
allow_flagging=False,

)`
I tried to get rid of the variables but seems like gradio needs them
